# Extract pdf pages from file based on a specific text

Tags: python, pdf

I have a huge pdf file with different pages. Each page has a code that represents a result. The thing is that the file has over 2k page results and it would be quite inefficient to do it one by one. What's one way with python to extract the page file with a specific text (code name) to a new pdf file?

Comment: Are you wanting to pull pages from a large PDF to make smaller PDF(s)?

Comment: Yes. Even if they are exported into a bigger one. As long as they have the specific text/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.